# Is it ok to not display an error when server side verification fails when JavaScript is required?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, client-side-validation, server-side-validation

We have a form that absolutely requires JavaScript to function, and validation is done client side. Validation is also performed server side, but it would be an extreme amount of work to get it to show errors when server side verification fails.

Since there is no chance for the user to not have JavaScript, is it OK to just fail with an HTTP error? The only way they would fail server side verification was if they either are a malicious user, or can't use JavaScript, in which case they wouldn't be using the form anyway.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say this is fine, *except* for a certain class of errors.

Some validation errors are not a result of malice but simply cannot be checked and discovered at any other time than when the form is actually processed. This can be because of a scarce resource that needs to be reserved but cannot be ("this username is already in use"), or because of some server-side recoverable error ("The upstream Credit Card processor is not responding. Please try again later").  For these kinds of errors, you absolutely should have some kind of error message communicated back to the user.  It's hard to envision a design where sending these kinds of errors back would not be possible. At the very least you can do this:

1. Send your HTTP error response (4xx or 5xx depending on the nature of the error)
2. In the body of your response, package an error message in some data structure your javascript can understand easily. (JSON or XML, or even text/plain!  Remember to set the mime type.)
3. Have the error-handler for the javascript request insert the text of the error at a visible place in your form (e.g. at the top or near the submit button).

The most important thing, however, is to have server-side validation and not trust the client. You are already doing this, so if you want to do anything further it is a matter of polish and making for the best possible user experience. Sometimes that requires a disproportionate amount of effort and that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think it is fine.

Especially if a previous step in using the site would also not work at all without Javascript, so the user couldn't have proceeded to the page in question without Javascript, then going to the huge expense of making it work without Javascript is wasted effort. For example, in .Net webforms, logging in requires Javascript, so any pages inside the secured area of the site can, to my mind, assume Javascript is available.

I'm curious what other people think, though.

Answer (score 0):

If the only expected use case for failing the http request is when someone has bypassed the browser, then just failing the http request seems perfectly fine.  You aren't impacting any expected user scenario, yet you are still protecting the server-side integrity with server-side validation.  There's no point in doing more work than that.  Seems fine to me.

What would make it worth it to do more work to show error UI from the server would be if there are actual legitimate user scenarios where bad data would get through to the server.  But, since you think that is unlikely or impossible for a legitimate scenario to go there, then there's no reason do do that extra work.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok so long as you are certain that the client side validation and server-side validation are equivalent. On that note, I find it hassle some to keep the client-side validation code and server-side validation code in sync (Especially if they are written in different languages, which is always the case if you are not using node.js or GWt). If anyone has any solution that it would be great.

However, if there are certain validation that can only be performed on server-side (database uniqueness constraint, for instance), then it is important to show user that their client-side actions have failed. That depends on the application itself though.